# What granularity does memory channel interleaving occur when enabled in BIOS?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, intel, ram, amd-processor

Memory channel interleaving is a method of setting a physical address area which can be enabled in BIOS, so that all memory channels are alternately used to achieve best bandwidth and latency.

I want to know at what granularity memory channel interleaving occurs, in other words, what is the minimum memory block size that will be guided to the same memory channel when performing memory channel interleaving?

In [this article](https://www.betriebssysteme.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Hillenbrand.pdf), it could be 2^7 = 128 bytes.

In [this whitepaper from fujitsu](https://sp.ts.fujitsu.com/dmsp/Publications/public/wp-skylake-memory-performance-ww-en.pdf), "The channel interleave block size is based on a cache line size of 64 bytes"

**Are there any official materials from Intel or AMD that can explain how this memory channel interleaving configuration works?**

Comment: The DDR SDRAM burst transfer size is 64 bytes, so it's certainly possible that physical address-space alternates between memory controllers with that granularity, for halves of 128-byte pairs of cache lines.  That would give the most parallelism for sequential accesses, and for the L2 spatial prefetcher to hit the other DRAM controller.  (OTOH, fetching two adjacent lines from the same memory controller would mean it avoids having to change "rows" aka "dram pages" between accesses.)  Still, I'd guess 64 byte granularity for the interleave, which you could describe as 128-byte pairs.